# JAVA check if a string does not contain a sub string from a string array,

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, loops

Hello I must be tired as I just can't seem to make this work, in my mind it makes sense. I have a `String[]` full of Android app names that I am trying to filter out before I write the results to a `JSONArray`.

```
 public static JSONArray appInfo = new JSONArray();
 public static String[] ignoreList = {"Google", "Maps", "Settings", "Phone", "Chrome", "Photos", "Duo", "YouTube", "Gmail", "Contacts", "Drive", "Clock", "Messages", "Files", "Calculator", "File manager", "Samsung", "Gallery", "LastPass", "OnePlus", "Weather"};

public void listApps(Context c) {

    PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
    Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);


    for (ResolveInfo resolve_info : packages) {
        try {
            String package_name = resolve_info.activityInfo.packageName;
            String app = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(package_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            for (String tempStr : ignoreList) {
                if (!app.contains(tempStr)) {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); // Create temp json object with app info.
                    json.put("app", app);
                    appInfo.put(json);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        Log.d("Debug", appInfo.toString(4));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If I was to check;

```
if (!app.contains("Google")) {
```

etc.. Then my `JSONArray` would contain no app names with "Google" but when I iterate over the `ignoreList` I get the following `JSON` out which is from the `ignoreList` not the remaining items that are not in the `ignorList`? Also it keeps repeating the objects? Any help would be very welcomed.

```
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Chrome"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Phone"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Settings"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Google Play Store"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Drive"
    },
    {
        "app": "Maps"
    },
    {
        "app": "Maps"
    },
    {
        "app": "Maps"
    },
    {
        "app": "Maps"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have two issues:

1. **Repetition issue:** because you don't break the for loop whenever you add your `app` to the JSON list, so you continue iterating
   the `ignoreList` and add more instances of the `app` to the JSON
   list. to avoid that you need to add a `break` statement.
2. **Adding apps that should be ignored:** this is because you are adding the `app` to the JSON list before comparing every
   instance from the `ignoreList` the `app`.. it looks vague and also
   to me :) so I will explain with example.

Example:

Consider your app = "**Settings**", and now you are comparing it to the list using the for loop, so first you compare it to "**Google**", it doesn't equal it, so add it to the `JSON list`, the same applies when you compare it to "**Maps**", and so on until you compare it to "**Settings**", at this time it won't be added to the `JSON list`, but you already added it multiple times before you reach to "Settings", so you need to wait until you finish your entire iterations before adding the `app` to the `JSON list`. I used a `boolean` to achieve that.

```
public void listApps(Context c) {

    PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
    Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolve_info : packages) {
        try {
            String package_name = resolve_info.activityInfo.packageName;
            String app = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(package_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            boolean isIgnored = false;

            for (String tempStr : ignoreList) {

                if (app.toLowerCase().contains(tempStr.toLowerCase())) {
                    isIgnored = true;
                    break; // to avoid unneeded iterations
                }
            }
            if (!isIgnored) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); // Create temp json object with app info.
                json.put("app", app);
                appInfo.put(json);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        Log.d("Debug", appInfo.toString(4));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response and taking the time to answer, it makes perfect sense.